# Why is Horus demanding to be rebooted EVERY time I do an update?

Tags: updates

Curious what's going on here.

***EVERY*** time I do an update from the Daemon, Horus demands to be restarted.

Is it channeling it's inner Windows?

This seems **VERY** un-Linux like.

Any thoughts?

And why isn't there a release-horus tag?

And why in the world can I only post every 40 minutes?

So many questions, so little time....

Comment: Most likely an incomplete update, broken PPA maybe? You could run a `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, reboot then `sudo apt autoclean` and `sudo apt autoremove` in Terminal to see what is going on there. After that run a `flatpak update`, maybe something's borked on the flatpak side? if you see some error messages, add them to your question.

Comment: The amusing part is update/upgrade does it's thing without demanding a reboot. I've purposely eliminated all flatpak software due to file access (interoperability) issues.  Why won't this inane daemon allow me to use carriage returns to separate thoughts?

Comment: Do the autoclean and autoremove commands from my comments do anything? Does the `flatpak list` command return nothing? THe comments do not really allow for  much formatting, all new relevant info can be added by editing your original question.

Comment: Sorry, missed the question. Autoclean and autoremove work as advertised.